# How to right check file in the AWS S3 bucket

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have converter, I added a file into input bucket than AWS Lambda convert this file to another format and than added it to output bucket, after than I download this file. If file has a litle size converting is fast, but if file has big size it may has take many time. How to right check is there this file?

I just recursively use the function for check:

```
convertingFile(fileName) {
  this.isConverting = true

  const params = {Bucket: BUCKET_OUTPUT_NAME}

  this.s3Client.listObjects(params)
  .promise()
  .then(data => {
    for (let file of data.Contents.values()) {
      if (file.Key === fileName) {
        console.log('There is the file: ' + fileName + ' in the bucket')
        this.isConverting = false
        this.downloadFile(fileName)
      }
    }

    if (this.isConverting) {
      console.log('There is no the file: ' + fileName + ' in the bucket, try to find again')
      this.convertingFile(fileName)
    }
  }).catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

But it make many request. How to make it better?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how your app is structured, but I would recommend decoupling the part which downloads the processed file into its separate Lambda function.

This way you will have 2 simple options:

1. Create S3 notification for object creation and react to it: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html
2. Send "conversion done" message to a SQS queue from the part of the app which does the converting, include S3 object key in it. Then configure lambda to receive messages from queue.

There certainly are more possibilities, but this is just a general idea.